# Angular 6: problems with opening index.html

Tags: angular6

While developing my project, I always opened it with this command:

`ng serve -o`

However, when I tried to open `index.html` from the project folder, it displayed an empty page

I've tried to find an answer, but it was unsuccesful due to the fact that most questions were about a failed compilation.

Can someone tell me how to open `index.html`?

Comment: Please post your code?

Comment: It can be usefull to share screenshot and your code